# SQL Server combine Update and Delete

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to combine both update and delete in a single SQL statement? I would like to execute something like this:

```
update a
set a.value = a.value + b.value
from Table1 a
join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Also, rows, which has value higher than some constant number, should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to arrange this in one statement using `MERGE`, adding the limiting maximum clause to the matching rule (the condition in `using <source> on <condition>`), and using `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE DELETE`. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx for more detail on `MERGE`.

Performing the two operations in a transaction would make your code clearer though, so that would probably be the better option. Also note that `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE DELETE` is not part of any standard for the `MERGE` statement (it is an MS SLQ Server extension) so if portability is a concern that needs to be considered.

Comment: [Required reading, IMHO, for anyone considering `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine them in one statement but you can wrap them into one transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  update a
  set a.value = a.value + b.value
  from Table1 a
  join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID;

  DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Value > @Constant;
COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using procedure or trigger for this type of problem is better i think

**PROCEDURAL WAY**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE(IN Required_params DATA_TYPE())
   BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
    BEGIN
        SET output = 0;
        ROLLBACK ;
    END;

   START TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE a SET a.value = a.value + b.value FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b ON    a.ID = b.ID ;

    DELETE  FROM table1 where some_row>const;

  COMMIT ;
END
```

OR 
**USING TRIGGER**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `dele`
AFTER UPDATE ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW 

 BEGIN 
  SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
  DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE some_row>const;
  SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
 END
```

Comment: This all looks like MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MERGE command, something like this (this a dummy code, ok?):

```
MERGE YourTale AS pi
     USING (SELECT col1,col2 
            FROM YourTable) AS src (col1,col2)
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN DELETE
```

You can learn more about MERGE command here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb510625.aspx